# Can we get a zoom scale with the help of the dimentions(width & height) of the element in js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, d3.js, d3-force-directed

Im currently facing the issue with the zoom level in d3.js

I got the dimentions for `<g className ="_zoomElement">` element with the help of this function

```
const g = select("._zoomElement")
      console.log(g.node().getBBox())
```

I want to fit the group element into the svg Canvus according to the svg dimentions with the help of one button click
I got the svg canvus width and height dimentions too

**Explanation Image**

[image]

i dont know how to find the scale value with the help of dimentions

i thought like this

if parent element dimetions would be like this
`width = 1000px height = 500px`

i will reduct 2% from that values we get the fit ratio

but my concern how can we get zoom scale value with that values

Comment: Suppose that `let bb = g.node().getBBox()` Make the svg's `viewBox = "bb.x bb.y bb.width bb.height"` Also use no width or height for the svg element letting it take the width of the parent conteiner. If you need to set the size of the svg element use only the width

Answer (score 0):

finally i  found the answer myself by searching on d3.js zoom to fit example
then i found solution on this post [click to view](http://bl.ocks.org/TWiStErRob/b1c62730e01fe33baa2dea0d0aa29359)

```
function zoomFit(paddingPercent, transitionDuration) {
 var bounds = view.node().getBBox();
var parent = view.node().parentElement;
var fullWidth = parent.clientWidth,
  fullHeight = parent.clientHeight;
var width = bounds.width,
  height = bounds.height;
var midX = bounds.x + width / 2,
  midY = bounds.y + height / 2;
if (width == 0 || height == 0) return; // nothing to fit
var scale =
  (0.79 || 0.75) / Math.max(width / fullWidth, height / fullHeight);
var translate = [
  fullWidth / 2 - scale * midX,
  fullHeight / 2 - scale * midY,
];
svg
  .transition()
  .duration(200 || 0)
  .call(
    zoom.transform,
    d3.zoomIdentity.translate(...translate).scale(scale)
  );
```

}

end of this code i got `translate` values and `scale`
this is the perfect code for zoom to fit
just attach that fuction to the main group

```
const root = select("._zoomElement") // main group seletion
  console.log(root.node().getBBox())
```

everything has worked fine for me